# How can I prevent my slideshow buttons from continuing past the last page?

Tags: wordpress, animation, button, slideshow

I'm making a complicated show room in Wordpress. I am using the posts to do this. It's actually going very well but I only have one problem: I have a next and prev button that slide the posts from left to right, but when they get to the last post the buttons still work so you get a white space.

This is my code.

```
<script>
$("#button-Next").click(function(){
  $("#inside").animate({"left": "-=800px"}, "slow");
  $("#button-Prev").animate({height:32}, "slow");
});

$("#button-Prev").click(function(){
  $("#inside").animate({"left": "+=800px"}, "slow");
});


$(function() {

    var longjohn = getElementById("#inside");

      if (longjohn.left = -1600px) {
          $("#button-Next").animate({height:0}, "slow");
      }

      if (longjohn.left = 0) {
          $("#button-Prev").animate({height:0}, "slow");
      }
      else {
            $("#button-Prev").animate({height:32}, "slow");
            $("#button-Next").animate({height:32}, "slow");
      }

    });
```

I cant find anything about setting the minimum length or something.

Comment: Welcome.  Something like [this](http://wpquestions.com/question/show/id/614) might be handy for you.  If you solve this yourself, make sure you post your answer so others can learn from your question.  Cheers~

Answer (score 0):

Use a Div to inclose the slide show in, set a class on the div e.g. `<div class="myslider"><!-- Your slide show code here --></div>` and from there use CSS to restrict the display of the div by setting the CSS properties to `.myslider{ display: block; width: 800px; height:300px; margin: 0 auto;` change the CSS properties to select what fits your necessary dimensions.

Alternatively you can set the position of each button using [CSS absolute positioning](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.asp).